# How to get access of the client side mqtt service in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, mqtt, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I checked the built-in mqtt service of Apache IoTDB, and seems like it only contains service on the server side. I want to know why there is no client side service of mqtt and how should I get access of this service in IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mqtt is used for data access, so it is implemented in server side, therefore you have to define the client side service yourself in Apache IoTDB.